# Nyquist with only poles at the origin

Tags: matlab, phase, control-systems

I need to solve this three exercises:
$$G_1(s) = \frac{1}{s}$$

$$G_2(s) = \frac{1}{s^2}$$

$$G_3(s) = \frac{1}{s^3}$$

This is what I did:
[image]

For the single pole ($1/s$), magnitude of A is $\infty$ and phase is 0

For the single pole ($1/s$), magnitude of B is $\infty$ and phase is -45

For the single pole ($1/s$), magnitude of C is $\infty$ and phase is -90

---

For the 2 poles one ($1/s^2$), magnitude of A is $\infty$ and phase is 0

For the 2 poles one ($1/s^2$), magnitude of B is $\infty$ and phase is -90 ($=2*(-45)$)

For the 2 poles one ($1/s^2$), magnitude of C is $\infty$ and phase is -180 ($=2*(-90)$)

---

For the 3 poles one ($1/s^3$), magnitude of A is $\infty$ and phase is 0

For the 3 poles one ($1/s^3$), magnitude of B is $\infty$ and phase is -135 ($=3*(-45)$)

For the 3 poles one ($1/s^3$), magnitude of C is $\infty$ and phase is -270 ($=3*(-90)$)

---

MATLAB can't do these Nyquist analysis in a correct way. That's why I'm asking here.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your answer is correct. Each pole gives 90 degrees phase lag. Furthermore, [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30123-nyquist-plot) can you download a file `lnyquist1` which is able to give a more accurate result when you have a pole at zero.

```
num = 1;
den = [1 0 0 0];
lnyquist1(num,den);
```

In addition, WolframAlpha is also able to give an accurate result, see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=nyquist%201%2Fs%5E3).

Comment: That's a nice script, but the infinite is too small I think. If an improvement can be made, infinite has to be something like 300 instead of 80.